# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой Call to a member function detach() on null

Tags: php, phpexcel

Всем добрый день!
Начну с того, что мой уровень знаний в PHP чуть выше 0, думаю, из-за этого и проблема... но это так, предисловие.
Имеется компонент Импорт/экспорт товаров из Excel в JoomShopping который установлен на сайт и вроде, как работает... но только до тех пор, пока я не поменял поля, которые мне нужно импортировать/экспортировать. Возникает эта ошибка, когда я в качестве поля указываю Атрибут или Характеристику товара, которую сам создал в JoomShopping.
Может, кто-нибудь объяснит, что ему от меня надо и как ему это дать?
Не знаю, даже какие файлы нужно смотреть из этого компонента, чтобы понять на что именно он ругается( Пожалуйста, если кому-то не в тягость, проведите меня за ручку до момента решения проблемы! Улучшение кармы с меня!

Comment: найдите вызов функции `detach()`, что-то типа `$var->detach();` так вот, этот самый $var не создается, а тогда его значение остается равным null. Вот в этом и ошибка

Comment: нашел по тексту такой кусок кода:
`код`
public function detach() {
  $this->_parent = NULL;
 }`код` что мне в нем на что следует заменить?

Comment: У вас в ошибке должен быть файл и строка где эта ошибка появляется. Как и написал @AlexanderChernin, ищите где вызывается detach()

Comment: в том-то и проблема, что оно не говорит, какой файл к ошибке привел( вот скрин страницы: https://i.imgur.com/i311pnw.png

Comment: в принципе, я уже даже готов обсудить цену скромного финансового вознаграждения, если найдется тот чудесный человек, который поможет решить проблему

Comment: включил отображение ошибок: увидел такую портянку: [ссылка](https://i.imgur.com/QP7Q04y.png)

Comment: я же с такой толпой файлов в жизни не разберусь( возьмитесь, кто-нибудь разобраться, пожалуйста!

Comment: Здесь не сайт фриланса, рекомендую пойти туда и найти специалиста для решения ваших проблем через наемный труд.